# Textbox caret isn't moving WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, caret

I am trying to move the textbox's caret to the start of the textbox when clicking on it with no success.
I tried multiple approaches and was always getting the same result of the caret position not changing, is there anything in my code that could prevent the caret moving? is there a certain event I need to use?

This is my XAML:

```
<TextBox Name="roomNameBox"
         Text ="Room Name"
         Margin="23,0,0,0"
         GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus"
         LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"
         TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged">
```

And this is my code:

```
    private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TextBox box)
        {
            box.CaretIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TextBox box)
        {
            if (box.Opacity == 0.5)
            {
                box.Opacity = 1;
                box.CaretBrush = Brushes.White;
            }
        }
    }

    private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TextBox box)
        {
            if (box.Text == "")
            {
                if (box.Name == roomNameBox.Name)
                {
                    box.Text = Constants.ROOM_NAME_HINT;
                }
                else if (box.Name == timePerQuestionBox.Name)
                {
                    box.Text = Constants.TIME_PER_QUESTION_HINT;
                }
                else if (box.Name == maxPlayersBox.Name)
                {
                    box.Text = Constants.MAX_PLAYERS_HINT;
                }

                box.Opacity = 0.5;
                box.CaretBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(150, 169, 198));
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help

**Edit**: The code works only when I set a breakpoint and step the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `box.CaretIndex = 0;` in the GotFocus events for Keyboard and Mouse. See the CaretIndex property [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.caretindex?view=netcore-3.1).
Setting the index to 0 is translated to placing the caret before the first character (at index 0) of the text string content.

An event is firing after the GotFocus that is placing the caret at the end. The solution is to implement these two events:

```xaml
<TextBox 
Keyboard.GotKeyboardFocus="TextBox_GotKeyboardFocus" Mouse.GotMouseCapture="TextBox_GotMouseCapture"  
Text="test"></TextBox>
```

```
private void TextBox_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBox).CaretIndex = 0;
}

private void TextBox_GotMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBox).CaretIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: It did not work for me. any idea why it might do that?

Comment: Thank you so much! I was researching for hours and couldn't find the solution

Comment: @Flametrav no problem. I love a challenge :)